# Comparing two csv files by non unique values from multiple columns, output to csv extra data where matched

Tags: python, csv, awk

I have run out of search terms and have come full circle. I've read and tried a ton of question and answers on what I thought would be a fairly simple task, but no joy.

I have two csv files.

```
**file1.csv** (2,000 + lines)<br/>
product_code, colour, size, sku, more cols..., barcode<br/>
<span style="color: red">
item98, red, XL, adfd56384678, ..., null<br/>
item99, black, L, adfgk9087467, ..., null<br/>
item98, red, S, adfgad240568, ..., null<br/>
</span>

**file2.csv** (20,000 + lines)<br/>
ITEM_CODE, COLOUR, SIZE, BAR_CODE<br/>
<span style="color: red">
item98, RED, XL, 090900887<br/>
item98, RED, S, 43581034<br/>
item97, BLUE, M, 519685371<br/>
</span>
```

I need to output:

```
**matched-result.csv** (2,000 + lines)<br/>
product_code, colour, size, sku, more cols..., barcode<br/>
<span style="color: red">
item98, red, XL, adfd56384678, ..., 090900887<br/>
item99, black, L, adfgk9087467, ..., null<br/>
item98, red, S, adfgad240568, ..., 519685371<br/>
</span>
```

The sku and barcode are unique values which can only be identified by matching product_code, size and colour. I need the barcode in a new column at the end of file1.csv. My first successful-ish attempt was using awk.

```
<pre>
awk -F',' -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,tolower($2),$3]=$4;next}{if( b = a[$1,tolower($2),$3]){ print $1,$2,$3,$4,b }}' file1.csv file2.csv > matched-result.csv
</pre>
```

I struggled outputting the whole of **file1.csv** with the results, trying **print $0,b** which created a new row with value of b. I would also like all of file1.csv output with empty values for non matches and the head if possible. I had to align the columns to match up for this awk approach to work, but the original fields don't align. This is no big deal to do, but I wonder if it's necessary of if there's a work around?

After that I tried to merge **file1.csv** with the awk output file **matched-result.csv** using a python script.

```
    import csv
    from collections import OrderedDict

    with open('file1.csv') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        dict1 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in r}

    with open('matched-result.csv') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        dict2 = OrderedDict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in r)

    result = OrderedDict()
    for d in (dict1, dict2):
        for key, value in d.iteritems():
            result.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)

    with open('desired-result.csv', 'wb') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        for key, value in result.iteritems():
            w.writerow([key] + value)
```

The output isn't the desired result. The order is wrong the number of records don't exactly match **file1.csv** there's an extra row? Also this two step approach seems disjointed and feels like one of these could do the job if done properly?

I have tried csvkit to join / merge the files but output 20,000 + rows some of which were duplicate. I think it treated the product_code/ ITEM_CODE columns as unique values, which they aren't. I have looked into join and grep but they don't seem to be the answer either.

I have installed panda and powerShell and willing to give them a go but don't know where to start with those, clear instructions needed there. Oh and i'm noob to all these languages and programs but not completely wet behind the ears.

hopefully I have given enough info to go on. I would have posted links to the posts of here I have read. You can take my work for it that it's +90% of them.

**Please can replies, offer code examples and preferably not a completely new language or approach.**

**// UPDATE**

I've voted for [@zwer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7553525/zwer)  answer because it more or less worked out the box bar a minor tweak, see the comments. But it's worth pointing out that [@RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13) awk method worked as well with the same result. I will pursue [@acushner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129600/acushner) panda method when / if I hear back and update this bit.

In case anyone cares, which I think is the best approach? Tomayto, tomarto, not sure that works in print. Personally, python is the easier to read. Awk is nice and short, I *think* it's a regex based language which I find harder to understand and was steeper learning curve.

**Thanks to everyone who commented. I was wrestling with this for a long time and got it sorted on here pronto.**

Comment: use `pandas.read_csv` and then `join` on the three columns from each that you need

Comment: @acushner I've installed panda but not had a look yet. Can you offer me a complete code example to try please mate?

Comment: you should definitely play around with it then. and i was mistaken, you should use `merge`, not `join`

Comment: sample usage would be: `df.merge(df2, left_on=['a', 'b'], right_on=['A', 'B'])`

Comment: Thanks @acushner. I'm going to need to look at the documentation into panda before I can try your approach. If I can figure it out I will let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and versatile Python approach:

```
import csv

# load the second file in memory as we need it for a barcode lookup
barcodes = {}  # will hold a map for our barcode values
with open("file2.csv", "rU") as f:  # open file2.csv for reading
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # create a CSV reader, you may need to tweak its options
    next(reader)  # skip the header
    for row in reader:  # loop it row by row
        # store code:color:size map as a tuple in our barcodes map
        barcodes[(row[0], row[1].lower(), row[2])] = row[3]
# now you can get a barcode from it like: barcodes[("item98", "red", "XL")]

# open file1.csv for reading and matched-result.csv for writing
with open("file1.csv", "rU") as f, open("matched-result.csv", "w") as out:
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # create a CSV reader, you may need to tweak its options
    header = next(reader)  # get the header
    indexes = {column: index for index, column in enumerate(header)}  # map column indexes
    writer = csv.writer(out, lineterminator="\n")  # create a CSV writer for our output
    writer.writerow(header)  # write the same header to the output file
    for row in reader:  # loop through file1.csv rows
        # create a search map entry
        search = (row[indexes["product_code"]], row[indexes["colour"]], row[indexes["size"]])
        if search in barcodes:  # we have a barcode entry
            row[indexes["barcode"]] = barcodes[search]  # update it in the current row
        writer.writerow(row)  # write the potentially modified row to our output file
```

If there is a possibility of the `file2.csv` having columns in a different order you'll have to make sure that the mapping part ( `barcodes[(row[0], row[1].lower(), row[2])] = row[3]`) matches the column order, tho.

**EDIT** - Since I didn't test it before, I wrote a simple test to see if it's working so:

`file1.csv`:

```
product_code,colour,size,sku,added_col,barcode
item98,red,XL,adfd56384678,1,null
item99,black,L,adfgk9087467,2,null
item98,red,S,adfgad240568,3,null
```

`file2.csv`:

```
ITEM_CODE,COLOUR,SIZE,BAR_CODE
item98,RED,XL,090900887
item98,RED,S,43581034
item97,BLUE,M,519685371
```

And it results in `matched-result.csv` containing:

```
product_code,colour,size,sku,added_col,barcode
item98,red,XL,adfd56384678,1,090900887
item99,black,L,adfgk9087467,2,null
item98,red,S,adfgad240568,3,43581034
```

If your CSV files follow a structure as presented in the question, like these do, it should work just fine. The only problem I could potentially see in your data is that there is a space after a comma that separates the values. If that's indeed the case with your data add `skipinitialspace=True` to the arguments of each `csv.reader()` (e.g. `reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)`) to account for the extra space. As I wrote in the code, you might need to tweak the `csv.reader()/csv.writer()` options to match your CSV dialect.

Comment: Thanks @zwer for the example, super helpful comments too. I've tried the code but it isn't populating the barcode column? The columns of file1 and file2 are mapped in relation to their numeric value, 0, 1, 2 etc. but the names of the columns differ. Looking at your code it doesn't look like this should matter? I have double checked the column names align (line 22) of the search part. Not sure what else to try?

Comment: I changed line 22 of the search to make it look lower case `search = (row[indexes["productcode"]], row[indexes["color"]].lower(), row[indexes["size"]])`  and bingo, it worked like a charm ! Muchos gracias amigo!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is some inconsistency in your output, ideally last line of your shown output shouldn't be there if we are considering $1,$2 and $3 as index of file2.csv file.

If yes that is a typo then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F", " 'FNR==NR{;a[$1,tolower($2),$3]=$NF;next} (($1,$2,$3) in a){$NF=a[$1,$2,$3]} 1' file2.csv file1.csv
```

**EDIT**: As OP has control M characters in Input_file(s) so adding following to it too now.

```
awk -F", " '{gsub('/\r/',"")} FNR==NR{;a[$1,tolower($2),$3]=$NF;next} (($1,$2,$3) in a){$NF=a[$1,$2,$3]} 1' file2.csv file1.csv
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 for your reply. I tried your code example but the BAR_CODE field values from file2.csv weren't appended to the matched-result.csv file? But then it doesn't print an output that I can see?

Comment: user2... - Ravinders code is correct and the only way that can not produce any output is if file2.csv is empty or your awk is broken in a way I've never seen before. Are you sure you copy/pasted the code correctly? Ravinder - remember to set `OFS`.

Comment: @EdMorton I copied and pasted it directly. I added > matched-result.csv to the end to output it as a csv file `awk -F", " 'FNR==NR{;a[$1,tolower($2),$3]=$NF;next} (($1,$2,$3) in a){$NF=a[$1,$2,$3]} 1' file2.csv file1.csv > matched-result.csv` The existing barcode column remains empty in the output. It might help to know what to look for in the output. ie. where the barcode info is meant to be in the output. Looking at the one liner and seeing the '1' I'm making an assumption it would add a new column to the end of the outputted csv file?

Comment: @user2078890: could you please check 2 things, 1st make sure no carriage characters are there(by doing cat -v Input_file) if you see any control M characters or etc you have to remove them then by doing (tr -d '\r' '' < Input_file). 2nd option is I am making field separator as -F", " which means it is having comma with a space as a field separator in case your Input_file doesn't have comma and space then only use comma as a field separator is what I could say as of now.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 when I `cat -v file1.csv` all line endings have ^M at the end. Are they control M characters? If I try your suggestion `tr -d '\r' '' < file1.csv` I get the following output `usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2` When I look again it still has them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cool, so it means control M only the culprit here. So you could you please try my EDITED version solution now. Also in previous comment change tr command to (tr -d '\r' < Input_file), let me know how it goes then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 bingo! You nailed it. Thanks Bud!

Comment: @user2078890: So this is correct answer, hope so ;)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 not sure I can vote for both, can I? I have updated the post to credit your approach and say it's worked. zwer was the quickest route to goal and so have left his as the right answer. Does that make me a bad person? :P Cheers anyway dude!

Comment: No, it was on a lighter note, I appreciate your attitude for learning and sharing, keep it up and keep learning. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

using `pandas` is pretty straightforward. you would just do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df_sku = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', index_col=False)
df_bc = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', index_col=False)
res = df_sku.merge(df_bc, left_on=['product_code', 'colour', 'size'], right_on=['ITEM_CODE', 'COLOUR', 'SIZE'])
```

give this a shot and let me know how you make out. additionally, if you're going to be doing a bunch of csv stuff, `pandas` is 100% worth learning.

Comment: I placed you code in a file pandas-sort.py and ran it in Terminal and I got a syntax error `python pandas-sort.py
  File "pandas-sort.py", line 5
    res = df_sku.merge(df_bc, left_on=['productcode', 'color', 'size', right_on=['ITEM_CODE', 'INVT_LEV2', 'INVT_LEV3'])
                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` NB: The column names have changed to match the real world column names. I also don't see how it outputs to matched-results.csv. i'm happy to keep trying this as an alternative approach.

Comment: yeah, there was a syntax error, which you should be able to debug. in any case, it's fixed now (missing right `]` in the list passed to `left_on`)

Comment: great that fixed it. And the output to csv?

Comment: `res.to_csv(filename, index=False)`.